# How can I use current user (default membership) as a data field in DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I am new to asp.net. I have a details view control on my page. I use linq to sql. My details view is an admin panel for data entry page. So some members will enter some news to my database. I want to use "Writer" Data Field to be filled automaticly with the current logged user. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply need to inject the username into the field at some point.

There is not a point-n-click drag-n-drop solution to this case, and there are many ways to accomplish this and to go into further detail is likely not necessary.

Just get the value into the textbox or field as the page is served where L2S can pick it up on the postback.